# Comparing/Contrasting Adjectives with/without "the" and "one"

Tags: american-english, articles, omissibility

In terms of American English, I'm considering the following 3 options of comparing/contrasting adjectives. Are all of these okay?

1. The red dress is better than **blue**.
2. The red dress is better than **the blue**.
3. The red dress is better than **the blue one**.

Another example,

4. The American death rate is greater than **British**.
5. The American death rate is greater than **the British**.
6. The American death rate is greater than **the British one**.

Comment: Welcome to ELU! I took the liberty of altering your numbering. It makes the sentences easier to refer to without having to write them out in full.  My answer would be that 2, 3, and 6 are correct. However I am British so wait for an answer from the US.

Comment: The red is better than the blue. If not, it could be 'Red is better than blue' without definite article at both the places. 'The' preceding red, and not blue' ? 2) The American death rate is higher than the British death rate/ than that of Britain.

Comment: I agree with Chasly that 1 and 4 are unacceptable (you are not comparing the red dress with the colour blue in general). However, I prefer 5 to 6. "The (adjective) one" seems a bit informal for discussing something as serious as death rates. Even better is Ram's suggestion "...than that of Britain".

Comment: Are 1 and 4 *informally* acceptable, or would they actually be considered foreign?

Comment: @geneb. They're not idiomatic at all. You could say "Red is a better dress color than blue".